# Parameter pack form of 'auto ... arg' is enabled in lambda but not in function?

Tags: c++, gcc, parameters, lambda, clang

Can someone explains me why a parameter can be declared as '`auto ... arg`' in this context (when used in a lambda):

```
    auto glambda = [](auto a, auto&& b) { return a < b; }; 
    bool b = glambda(3, 3.14); // OK

    auto vglambda = [](auto printer) { 
        return [=](auto ... ts) { // OK: ts is a function parameter pack 
            printer(std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)...);
            return [=]() { printer(ts ...); };
        };
    };

    auto p = vglambda( [](auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) { std::cout << v1 << v2 << v3; } ); 

    auto q = p(1, 'a', 3.14); // OK: outputs 1a3.14 q(); // OK: outputs 1a3.14
```

Life [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/g5ztFNCpjUPFgXMm).

But not in this (when used in a function):

```
void func(auto ... arg)
{
}
```

Life [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Pta4QCMrxV2tTpkg).

I would be very happy of a detailed explanation with a quotes from the latest ISO C++ draft. Or is this a bug of clang compiler? Because it compiles fine actually under gcc 5.0.

Comment: The latest one will be best. But I would also like some document references.

Comment: Well, it's not valid till at least C++14. The Concepts TS, which might make it in some form into C++1z, would allow it though: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function

Comment: Seems not to be in the latest draft yet for C++1z.

Comment: What? Can you explain in a little more detail what are you talking about?

Comment: Well, using placeholder-types in function-arguments (not lambda-arguments) is in the Concepts TS, but that's not part of even the current C++1z draft. Yet. So it's simply not allowed.

Comment: Any rationale for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. It's stated in 'n4296' at § 5.1.2.5:

> The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression has a public
>   inline function call operator (13.5.4) whose parameters and return
>   type are described by the lambda-expression’s
>   parameter-declaration-clause and trailing-return-type respectively.
>   For a generic lambda, the closure type has a public inline function
>   call operator member template (14.5.2) ***whose template-parameter-list
>   consists of one invented type template parameter for each occurrence of
>   auto in the lambda’s parameter-declaration-clause, in order of
>   appearance***. **The invented type template-parameter is a parameter pack
>   if the corresponding parameter-declaration declares a function
>   parameter pack (8.3.5).** The return type and function parameters of the
>   function call operator template are derived from the
>   lambda-expression’s trailing-return-type and
>   parameter-declarationclause by replacing each occurrence of auto in
>   the decl-speciﬁers of the parameter-declaration-clause with the name
>   of the corresponding invented template-parameter.

This means that something like this:

```
[](auto ... arg) {}
```

Is roughly equivalent to:

```
template<class ... tmp>
ClosureType::operator()(tmp ... arg);
```

However I don't know why isn't this also allowed in normal functions. Perhaps someone should propose it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works now.

```
auto f(auto stuff...){ std::cout << "You landed here!" << std::endl;}
```

I wound up here via a google search, so this is for whoever else winds up here in the future.  Looks like we got it with C++17.

Comment: That's a variadic function, not a parameter pack. Parameter pack would look like `auto... stuff`.